# ngx-bootstrap DatePicker DateTime issue in Angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, ngx-bootstrap

I have a SQL Server database field named 'JoiningDate' which has the type date (no time part here).To Capture the input from the user I am using [ngx-bootstrap datepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker) but the problem is that whenever I select a date from the datepicker, the datepicker itself converting the selected date into utc datetime as follows:

[image]

Sometimes it mismatches the date part due the utc time part.

My questions are:

1. **How can I get the the selected date as plain string like [jQueryUI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?**
2. **What is the best option get the input date exactly as it shown in
       input field?**

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a simple function to convert the date object to the locale date string in format ("10/31/2018"),  just as it is displayed in the input field:

```
convertDate(inputDate) {  
    // convert date received to locale string in 10/31/2018 format  
    const localeDate = inputDate.toLocaleDateString();  
    return localeDate;  
}
```